# react-navigation/native-stack could not be found when imported in expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

After installing react-navigation following the documentation on their official website for expo project, still getting the error of react-navigation/native-stack could not be found within directories, has anyone come across this error and what could possibly be the way out

Comment: Did you tried also building the application again ? npx run android for android devices.

Comment: I am using expo, not the react-native cli, it's an expo project, and i have deleted the node_modules and package-lock.json reinstalled all dependecies still the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally resolve the issue, I couldn't post earlier, been busy with projects, I have to install react-navigation/native and react-navigation/native-stack
`npm install @react-navigation/native` and
`npm install @react-navigation/native-stack`
I installed both separately and the issue has been resolved, Thanks everyone that tried to help